# GregorianCalendar и ArrayList

Tags: java

Как правильно добавить элементы `GregorianCalendar` в `List`.
Есть код где читаю строки по разделителю числа добавляю в один лист, а дату необходимо сохранить в другом, потом с ней будут манипуляции..,почему то на строке `listGt.add(gt);` значения корректно не добавляются, а замещаются?

```
private Date parsingDate=null;

private GregorianCalendar gt=new
GregorianCalendar(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.YEAR);

private List>GregorianCalendar> listGt=new ArrayList<>();

while((string=r.readLine())!=null)
{
    for(String i:string.split((";")))
    {
        if(i.matches("^-?\\d+$"))//определяем является ли прочитанная строка числом
        {

            value.add(Double.parseDouble((i)));
        }

        try
        {
            parsingDate=dt.parse(i);//анализирует строку для получения даты
            gt.setTime(parsingDate);
            listGt.add(gt);
        }
        catch(ParseException x)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Потому что это ссылочный тип.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   parsingDate = dt.parse(i);
   gt = new GregorianCalendar(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.YEAR);
   gt.setTime(parsingDate);
   listGt.add(gt);
```